# dynamic generated button JQuery dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have problem with dynamic generated buton from typeahead twitter:

```
templates: {
empty: [
    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm form-add' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#form-add' data-title='Add' data-text='abc' data-form-action='' data-parent-id=" + $(self).data("parent-id") + ">Add</button>"
].join("\n"),
suggestion: function(data) {
    return "<p>" + data.name + "</p>";
}}
```

and I would like send `data-parent-id` to my modal on click event on button Add and this not work.

```
$("button.form-add").on("click", function(e) {
console.log("typeahead"); });
```

What is wrong ?

Regards

Comment: use `$(document).on("click","button.form-add", function(e) {` delegate the event

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)